# Using CFIF for cfquery result

Tags: mysql, coldfusion-10

I have made a login form and have saved some distinct user ID and Password and one admin login in database.
I want if admin logs in it goes to admin page and if someone else logs in , it should check for the entered User_name and User_pass in the database and if match is found then redirects to home page index.cfm else asks for a valid User_name or USer_pass..

```
<cfif #Form.name# eq 'admin' AND #Form.pass# eq 'admin'>

    <cflocation url="/cooker.envato.tabvn.com/admin_index.cfm"/>
<cfelse>
    <cfquery name="myquery" datasource="cfdb2">
    select User_name ,User_pass from Uid_pass where User_name='#form.name#' AND User_pass='#form.pass#'
```

Actually i am stuck with the cfif conditons and not able to write the exact cfif conditions to check for the relevant user....

please help me with this

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "stuck"? What exactly is your current code doing? What *should* it be doing instead?

Comment: Your code example is incomplete, but one way would be to do something like:

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is incomplete, but one way would be to do something like:

```
</cfquery><!--- ending your code --->

<cfif myquery.RecordCount EQ 1>
    <cflocation url="your normal login page" addtoken="no"/>
<cfelse><!--- either no record returned or more than one - either is bad --->
    do stuff here to deal with bad logins
</cfif>

</cfif><!--- ends your if statement --->
```